# Median Grouped ported from Python to C++?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++11, c++17, c++14

I am trying to port Python median_grouped function from statistics built in module to C++.

Anyway, somewhere I'm missing something because my code doesn't work.

It should be: median_grouped([1, 3, 3, 5, 7], interval=1) = 3.25 and median_grouped([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]) = 3.7.

My code result is always 0 no matter what the input is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int bisect_left(vector<int> &a, float x, int lo=0, int hi=0){
    /*"""Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.

    The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e < x, and all e in
    a[i:] have e >= x.  So if x already appears in the list, a.insert(x) will
    insert just before the leftmost x already there.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """
    */
    // First we sort the array
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());

    if (hi==0){
        hi = a.size();
    }

    while (lo < hi){
        int mid = (int)(lo+hi)/2;
        if (a[mid] < x){
            lo = mid+1;
        }
        else{
            hi = mid;
        }
    }

    return lo;
}
int bisect_right(vector<int> &a, float x, int lo=0, int hi=0){
    /*"""Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.

    The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e <= x, and all e in
    a[i:] have e > x.  So if x already appears in the list, a.insert(x) will
    insert just after the rightmost x already there.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """
    */
    // First we sort the array
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());

    if (hi==0){
        hi = a.size();
    }

    while (lo < hi){
        int mid = (int)(lo+hi)/2;
        if (x < a[mid]){
            hi = mid;
        }
        else{
            lo = mid+1;
        }
    }

    return lo;
}

int _find_lteq(vector<int> &a, int x){
    //'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    int i = bisect_left(a, x);
    if ((i != (int)a.size()) && (a[i] == x)){
        return i;
    }
    return 0;
}
int _find_rteq(vector<int> &a, int x, int l){
    //'Locate the rightmost value exactly equal to x'
    int i = bisect_right(a, x, 1, 0);
    if ((i != (int)a.size()+1) && (a[i-1] == x)){
        return i-1;
    }
    return 0;
}

float median_grouped(vector<int> &vec, int interval=1){
    float L=0.0;
    // First we sort the array
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    if(vec.size()==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(vec.size()==1){
        return vec[0];
    }
    /* Find the value at the midpoint. Remember this corresponds to the
    center of the class interval. */
    int x = vec[(int)vec.size()/2];
    for(int i=x; i<interval; i++){
        //The lower limit of the median interval.
        L = float(x) - float(interval)/2;
    }
    // Uses bisection search to search for x in data with log(n) time complexity
    // Find the position of leftmost occurrence of x in data
    int l1 = _find_lteq(vec, x);
    // Find the position of rightmost occurrence of x in data[l1...len(data)]
    // Assuming always l1 <= l2
    int l2 = _find_rteq(vec, x, l1);
    int cf = l1;
    int f = l2 - l1 + 1;
    return L + interval*(vec.size()/2 - cf)/f;

}

vector<int> vec{3, 5, 2, 7, 1, 3};
vector<int> vec_a{1,3,5,7};
vector<int> vec_c{ 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 8, 6 };
vector<int> a{1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5};
int main() {
    cout<< median_grouped(a,1)<<endl;
    cout<< median_grouped(a,2)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the function from statistics built in Python module that I am trying to port to C++:

```
def median_grouped(data, interval=1):
    """Return the 50th percentile (median) of grouped continuous data.

    >>> median_grouped([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5])
    3.7
    >>> median_grouped([52, 52, 53, 54])
    52.5

    This calculates the median as the 50th percentile, and should be
    used when your data is continuous and grouped. In the above example,
    the values 1, 2, 3, etc. actually represent the midpoint of classes
    0.5-1.5, 1.5-2.5, 2.5-3.5, etc. The middle value falls somewhere in
    class 3.5-4.5, and interpolation is used to estimate it.

    Optional argument ``interval`` represents the class interval, and
    defaults to 1. Changing the class interval naturally will change the
    interpolated 50th percentile value:

    >>> median_grouped([1, 3, 3, 5, 7], interval=1)
    3.25
    >>> median_grouped([1, 3, 3, 5, 7], interval=2)
    3.5

    This function does not check whether the data points are at least
    ``interval`` apart.
    """
    data = sorted(data)
    n = len(data)
    if n == 0:
        raise StatisticsError("no median for empty data")
    elif n == 1:
        return data[0]
    # Find the value at the midpoint. Remember this corresponds to the
    # centre of the class interval.
    x = data[n//2]
    for obj in (x, interval):
        if isinstance(obj, (str, bytes)):
            raise TypeError('expected number but got %r' % obj)
    try:
        L = x - interval/2  # The lower limit of the median interval.
    except TypeError:
        # Mixed type. For now we just coerce to float.
        L = float(x) - float(interval)/2

    # Uses bisection search to search for x in data with log(n) time complexity
    # Find the position of leftmost occurrence of x in data
    l1 = _find_lteq(data, x)
    # Find the position of rightmost occurrence of x in data[l1...len(data)]
    # Assuming always l1 <= l2
    l2 = _find_rteq(data, l1, x)
    cf = l1
    f = l2 - l1 + 1
    return L + interval*(n/2 - cf)/f
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with my C++ code, please?

Comment: To prevent people from making identifiers that conflict with the hidden stuff buried in the  compiler and library implementation there are [Rules about when and where you can use underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). Breaking these rules rarely bites, but when it does you come away feeling like one of the victims in a Jaws movie. Best that you know the rules and not break them

Comment: One of the best productivity tools you'll ever find is the debugger. With a debugger you can run the program at your speed and watch exactly what the program does as it does it. If you step line by line and keep a close eye on things, you can spot an unexpected event as it happens. The unexpected is a either a bug in the code or bad expectations. Either one needs to be fixed.

Comment: Unrelated: `int mid = (int)(lo+hi)/2;` No need for the cast. `int` plus an `int` always results in an `int`. Divide `int` by `int` and you also get an `int`.

Comment: I just copied the names exactly from Python implementation so everyone should recognize them. Thank you for pointing me for possible compiler problems!

Comment: I have used typecasting because Codeblocks is compaining about comparing different units as int vs vector.size() which is not int and it is throwing warnings everytime at compile time. But could this cause any problem? Just asking.

Comment: Also, I tried to debug and fix the code but it seems it is not doing the same thing as the one from Python does.